# How to make REST based WCF service Service file be index?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, rest

I have a service file, Service.svc that provides a Web Service. I would like the help page to be the main url (e.g. / instead of /Service.svc/help). Is this possible and can someone tell me how do do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just redirect to help page. For example:

```
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "", Method = "GET")]
public void RedirectToHelp()
{          
  WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Redirect;
  WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Location = "help";

}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked, although is there any way for the help page to ignore that?